# Editing /etc/hosts file OS X

Tags: linux, macos

I have a weird problem that is becoming rather annoying as I can't reason out why my edits to /etc/hosts file doesn't save. When I edit with sudo permissions and save them it looks fine. As soon as I open a new terminal or quit a terminal and check again the edits I made are gone.

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts/ or sudo vim /private/etc/hosts


 ##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

and I try to add this line: `127.0.0.1    ac-decountsv.example.com`
I also tried editing  the /private/etc/hosts/. Could some one tell me what am I overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: [`Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming`.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

OS X has a lock on changes to system files; remove the lock & make your changes.

This may help:
https://superuser.com/questions/40749/command-to-unlock-locked-files-on-os-x

Comment: I did try that before ! Sorry for not mentioning in  my questions. And also trying in the recovery mode. But still I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the file by using the below

```
chattr -i /etc/hosts; vi /etc/hosts;  chattr +i /etc/hosts
```